# How to change barcodes from one color to another one

Tags: sql, firebird, sql-delete

I´m trying to delete some duplicate barcodes from a Firebird database. The ERP I use matches all colors + sizes allocated at a table called characteristics. For example: Color - 'B001 - Black' Size - 'S'. It matches all colors with all sizes.

So for the 'B001 - Black' color I have barcodes for XS, S, M, L and XL sizes.

I have multiple colors and sizes for one product. In this case let´s call the article 'CFC0084645003' wich is in the table articles.

So I have 2 tables, one that holds all articles defined by a code that is 'CFC0084645003'. I also have a table that contains all the characteristics (Colors and sizes).

As I have translated the colors into Spanish so the same barcodes for 'B001 - Black' are the same as the translated color 'Negro'.

What I want to do is delete only the barcodes that are in the 'B001 - Nero + all sizes' to the translated color + sizes

The query I would use is this:

```
delete from barcode b join characteristics c on b.codobjet=b.codarticle where b.codarticle='CFC0084645003' and c.value='B001 - Black'
```

Thank you

Comment: Firebird does not support joins in `delete`. Please check the language reference for the correct syntax of [`delete`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-delete.html). You'll need to rewrite your query, see the linked duplicate.

Comment: I´m so sorry but whatching that SQL confuses me even more than what I am. Could you please explain me how should I make the SQL?

Comment: See the first code section in my answer, you will need to use an `exists` with a correlated subquery. Something like `delete from codbarra c where c.codarticulo = 'CFC0084645003' and exists (select * from carvalid d where d.codobjeto = c.codarticulo and d.valor='B021 - Bianco')` (test it first, as I have typed this without verifying it against Firebird!).

Comment: It does work. But it deletes the other records I have. For examle, I have 'B001 - Nero + XL' with barcode 10002544854. Doing this query it deletes the barcode with the 'B001 - Nero + XL' record. I just want to delete the 'B021 - Bianco' barcodes. Thank for your help man

Comment: I suggests you edit your question, include DDL, sample data, the expected result and actual result (for the given sample data) and I will reopen your question. It sounds to me like you need to add additional conditions to filter the data. It doesn't help that you have non-English table names, as that makes it harder to consider if there are other logical errors. Consider providing the example in your edited question with English table and column names.

Comment: Done, I hope it´s right now

Comment: Please provide the minimal table structure, a small set of example data for those tables and - given the example data - the expected data after deletion, and actual data after deletion.